# Traefik 2.0 & Docker TLS configuration error: failed to load X509 key pair

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, traefik

I have mounted the archive folder of letsencrypt and referenced the latest certificates in my dynamic configuration to play around and get to know traefik:

```
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /certs/pubkey.pem
      keyfile: /certs/privkey5.pem
      stores:
        - default
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: /certs/pubkey.pem
        keyFile: /certs/privkey5.pem
```

Extracted the pubkey: `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in fullchain5.pem  > pubkey.pem`

```
level=error msg="Error while creating certificate store default: failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
level=error msg="Unable to append certificate /certs/public.pem to store default: unable to generate TLS certificate : tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"
```

The labels of my web service:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`domain.tld`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.app.tls=true"
  - traefik.http.routers.app.service=service1
  - traefik.http.services.service1.loadbalancer.server.port=80
```

The setup seems to be fine but traefik just generates it's own certificate while the provided ones should be in the correct format and readable. Any ideas how to fix this and use the provided certificates?

Comment: Have you find the problem? Facing the same issue

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was due to symbolic links of the certificates in the live directory on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Docker can't handle symbolic links. Be aware when linking certificates from the live directory of Let's Encrypt and link the original paths. All certificates are stored in the archive folder.